# How to start hotspot with python

Tags: python, networking, operating-system, hotspot

How to turn on hotspot with python.
I tried a few times using subprocess but then it wont work for Linux or mac and also I don't know the code of how to turn the hotspot on with python. I really tried looking for solutions  to this problem. But none of the solutions showed how you can turn hotspot with python.

Any help is appreciated.